# Sending and retriving an email using a php form

Tags: php, aptana

I am attempting to retrieve a sender's email, sender's name, mail subject, and mail message sent.
You will also see in the code i want to check if the name, email address, and message of a sender are not empty using empty()function. If one of them are empty, i want to display an error message in the document. Otherwise, call send_email() function.

Right now my output is displaying parts of my code. I need help with the formatting or maybe I am missing a step.

```
<?php

    require_once ('c:/wamp64/www/Lab6/PHPMailerAutoload.php');

    function sendEmail($fromEmail,$fromName,$subject, $message){

        $mailer = new PHPMailer;
        $mailer->isSMTP();

        $mailer->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
        $mailer->Port = 587;

        $mailer->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
        $mailer->SMTPAuth = true;

        $mailer->Username= "geogumd@gmail.com";
        $mailer->Password= "gis@umd2016";

        $mailer->From= $fromEmail;
        $mailer->FromName=$fromName . "(" . $fromEmail . ")";

        $mail->IsHTML(true);

        $mailer->Subject=$subject;      
        $mailer->Body=$message;

        $mailer->addAddress('worthem.aleah@terpmail.umd.edu', 'Aleah');
        $mailer->Sendmail($fromEmail,$fromName,$subject,$message);

        if(!$mailer->send()) {
        $h = "Mailer Error " . $mailer->ErrorInfo;
        $m = "Mailer Error was not sent";
        print "<h1>$h</h1>";
        print "<pre>$m</pre>";
    }else{          
        print "<h1>Mail Sent</h1>";
        print "<p>Thank you. Your message has been sent successfully.</p>";
    }
    }
?>

<div id="content">
    <?php

    $user_input1 = $_POST['From'];
    $user_input2 = $_POST['FromName'];
    $user_input3 = $_POST['Subject'];
    $user_input4 = $_POST['Body'];

    if(!empty($user_input1) && is_string($user_input1)&&
    (!empty($user_input2) && is_string($user_input2))&&
    (!empty($user_input3) && is_string($user_input3))&& 
    (!empty($user_input4) && is_string($user_input4))
    )
        {
            sendEmail($user_input1, $user_input2, $user_input3, $user_input4);          
        }
    else{
            print "<h4>Sorry</h4>";
            print "<p>You didnt fill out the form completley. <a href='index.php?action=sendmail'>Try Again";
        }

    ?>
```

Comment: "my output is displaying parts of my code" what does that mean?

Comment: Maybe your server isn't actually running PHP, it's just serving up the source files. Have you tried testing that first?

Comment: This may be an issue. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php. If not, oh well.

Comment: @tadman It is my error is that $user_input1 = $_POST["From"];
    $user_input2 = $_POST["FromName"];
    $user_input3 = $_POST["Subject"];
    $user_input4 = $_POST["Body"];  are undefined indexes.

Comment: I think you're presuming `$_POST` has something in it and it doesn't. Also please, *please* get out of the habit of using exceedingly generic names like `$user_input1`. Name things what they are. If you called your children `Kid1` and `Kid2` they'd probably hate you for life.

Comment: The library has a debug function: `$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                        // Enable verbose debug output`.